# Why to use @WebServiceRef?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I found this question on Manning forum but there was no answer to it and it is something that 
interests me as well :

I'm a bit unclear of the benefit of using the `@WebServiceRef` annotation. Say you were injecting a Service (which would have to be generated by some tools ie wstools on jboss if using `jax-ws`), you would need this Service class stub as part of your deployment so you could just do:

```
private MyService service = new MyService();
```

as opposed to:

```
@WebServiceRef
MyService service;
```

Is the benefit of using the `@WebServiceRef` that you wouldn't be generating a new instance of the Service for each call which would be expensive. (I'm assuming the container can just hang on to the reference which would make things faster). However, what would happen then if I just made my Service **static**... ?

```
private static MyService service = new MyService();
```